# Set content inset in PDFView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pdf

I am using the new `PDFKit` framework (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit).

I would like, like in `UIScrollView`, to change the `contentInset` of my `PDFView`. 
Sadly, `PDFView` doesn't have a property `scrollView` or `contentInset`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think `PDFView` is a `UIView`, can you use that?

Comment: I could recursively iterate in my `PDFView` subviews in order to find a `UIScrollView` yes but that's an inelegant solution. I'm looking for something less hacky.

Comment: have you resolved this?

Answer (score 4):

PDFView doesn't have a publicly exposed UIScrollView property, but if you iterate the subviews you should find the that first subview is a PDFScrollView (UIScrollView subclass):

```
UIView *firstSubview = pdfView.subviews.firstObject;
if ([firstSubview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
    UIScrollView *pdfScrollView = (UIScrollView *)firstSubview;
    pdfScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20.0f, 0, 20.0f);
}
```

Otherwise the only other option I can think of is to inset the view itself:

```
pdfView.frame = CGRectInset(pdfView.frame, 10.0f, 10.0f);
```